# Book about Finite Element Method for PDES

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am looking for a book about Finite Element Method (FEM henceforth) for PDEs. A very good reference that I know is the book by Raviart and Thomas but it is in French and I do not understand it. The full reference is

P. Raviart & J.M. Thomas - Introduction à l’analyse numérique des équations aux dérivées partielles, Masson, 1988.

The approach of this book is purely analytical and no matrix theory is involved as well as MATLAB. Besides, this book is very self-contained (about 200 pages of contents).

Please, may you suggest me an equivalent reference in English?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered Ciarlet's book, The Finite Element Method for Elliptic problems? Is a well know reference in this topic and is more or less what you described except it is a lot longer ( about 600 pages)

Comment: Yes, I have. The exception is that it is too long but, fortunately, I noticed that there is a map to follow which allows me to skip the chapters that are not of primary importance. Thanks for the advice.